# Why do my thumbnails need to regenerate with every restart? Is it possible to allow them to persist?

Tags: nautilus, nemo, pcmanfm

I have a large amount of images on my machine and every single time I reboot the machine, I lose this cache, or at least it feels this way.

The folder I frequent the most often has around 3.6k images, but many others have a slightly smaller but similar number.

Very very often I spent maybe 5mins just scrolling through to let all the thumbnails generate only to come back at a later date and the thumbnails have disapeared.

How can I retain the generated thumbsnails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I know of looks like this:

Install the `dconf-editor` app:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Then open it, and either use its search feature to search for "thumbnail-cache", or for a similar effect, figure out the GUI and navigate to the `org.gnome.desktop.thumbnail-cache` location in it.

You will be presented with two settings: `maximum-size` and `maximum-age`. Upon clicking them, dconf-editor will reveal their description. From this can be seen, that a value of `-1` allows for no limits on the cache size and on the age of cached items.

Otherwise, you can provide a value in megabytes for the maximum cache size (which is 512 by default), and a value in days for the maximum thumbnail age (which is 180 by default).

---

If you would like to have a CLI solution, then executing the following in the terminal achieves the same:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.thumbnail-cache maximum-size -1

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.thumbnail-cache maximum-age -1
```

Take into consideration however that an unlimited thumbnail cache size may inflate the size of your `/home/<YOURUSERNAME>/` directory — this might matter if you did not assign it to a separate, dedicated partition.

---

Furthermore, you can keep an eye on the actual thumbnail files at this location:

```
/home/<YOURUSERNAME>/.cache/thumbnails/
```

Comment: Thanks Levente, this certainly looks to be on the right path :)